# Is Ninject Good for Production Applications?

Tags: .net, ninject

Wondering if anyone has used Ninject in a production application? And what pros and cons should one be aware of?

Comment: My understanding is that Ninject is used for http://www.agilezen.com, if that helps any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what sort of production applications. Generally speaking, I've deployed it to a couple of production apps without any problems. Having said that, the scale that those apps required was only a few hundred concurrent connections and it handled it fine. If you're talking about millions of concurrent connections you should probably do your due diligence and do some prototyping first.